# JavaScript Conditions for Audio Tag

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

How Java Script can help me so That if 1st song play then 2nd stop and if 2nd play then 1st stop

Comment: What have you done ? Can you show us some code ?

Comment: just share the code what you have done

Comment: See [this page](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/playlist.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two audio elements to do this a bit easier.

```
audio1.addEventListener( "play", function(){
    audio2.pause();
    audio2.currentTime = 0;
} );

audio2.addEventListener( "play", function(){
    audio1.pause();
    audio1.currentTime = 0;
} );
```

This will make the first audio tag to stop when the second is being played and vice versa. If you want to run automatically the second one, after first one ends, you can use

```
audio1.addEventListener( "ended", function(){
    audio2.play();
} );

audio2.addEventListener( "ended", function(){
    audio1.play();
} );
```

Hope that helps.